# Tap Click whatever finger motion event on iPhone 3GS

Tags: jquery-mobile

All I want to do is capture the event that a user taps an  and clear it. I can't get anything to work with iPhone 3GS.. There is barely any documentation on how to actually use jQuery mobile.. that I can find anyway.. so theese are my guesses mostly:

```
$("#wrap").live('pageinit', function() {
    $('#search_field').live('tap',function(event) {
        if ($(this).val() == "Search Applications") {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });
});
```

This borks my design and adds a "loading" header at the bottom of the page....

**Edit**: Seems like it randomly works on the 3GS but the most annoying is that just jQuery mobile destroys my site layout!! my submit button jumps down
()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just looking over you code are you trying to use a place holder and clear it if the user taps it? If so you can simply add an attribute to your HTML5 like this:

```
<imput type="text" placeholder="Search Applications" />
```

Live example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/KVuvm/
- http://jsfiddle.net/KVuvm/1/ (With jQM Look and Feel)
- http://jsfiddle.net/KVuvm/14/ (if you still wanted to use JS)

Comment: Wow thanks man! This was an assignment for a job and they suggested to use JavaScript. I'm assuming this will work for iPhone 3GS then! Will it work for Android devices aswell?

Comment: If the browser supports HTML5 the placeholder attribute will work, the jQuery should work as well for lower grade browsers